# Debugging not working for Spring Boot 2.2 and IntelliJ Idea

Tags: spring-boot, debugging, intellij-idea, maven-plugin

By running the app in debugging mode (spring-boot:run) with IntelliJ Idea CE, no breakpoints work at all when using Spring Boot 2.2. Instead, when rolling back to Spring Boot 2.1.1, everything works fine. What am I doing wrong? Is there an option/flag to add for 2.2 to make the debugger work?

Comment: Do you have something like `Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005` in your log.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I would recommend running the app directly from the IDE rather than using `mvn spring-boot:run`. Doing so will give you the best experience in the IDE.

The [release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#fork-enabled-by-default-in-maven-plugin) indicate that the Spring Boot Maven Plugin now forks the process by default which is the reason why you can't debug the application as you used to with `2.1`. If you really have to run the app using the maven plugin, you can disable forking the process (e.g. using `-Dspring-boot.run.fork=false`)

Comment: How can i run the application directly from IntelliJ Idea Community Edition?

Comment: Run the main method

Comment: Same problem here. It doesn't work with  spring-boot:run. Click right button over the main application class and select "Debug XXXX.main()". Now you will be able to stop it.

Comment: Above works off course.
If you use externalized properties, add the following to the VM options of the Spring Boot configuration for your "Application"  in "Run/Debug" configurations :   "-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/application.yml,file:${HOME}/conf/application.yml"

Note that this is the old way to add external configurations, since Spring Boot 2.2 you add it with -Dspring-boot.run.jvmArguments="-Dspring.config.location=etc..."

Answer (score 0):

Edit Configuration -> Application -> in Main Class: select your Main class (the one that contain your main method(public static void main) ) and run

Comment: This doesn't even come close to address the original question.

Comment: I had the same issue working with IntelliJ Idea community version with that version of spring boot, when I was running as maven project, but I changed to run it as normal java app and the debugging works just fine

Answer (score 0):

with spring boot 2.7 just add the below command on IntelliJ IDE configuration setting in Run options.

spring-boot:run -Dspring-boot.run.fork=false